# Simulating solar system with Newton's law

Tags: orbital-motion, planets, celestial-mechanics, solar-system, software

I made a simulation in C++ with Newtons law and test it comparing the planets positions with the position from Solar system Calculator Don Cross (which I converted from JavaScript to  C++) 
http://cosinekitty.com/solar_system.html

What I do is every time step(usually 1 second but step 0.2 second is very similar to 10 seconds step) :

1. Calculate accelaration ( $= $ newton forzes $\times$ deltatime)
2. Update speed and positions
3. Compare postions with results from Don Cross solar calculator alghorithms

   But after **10 days** of simulation I get this **distance deviation** (to the calculator from Don Cross) results :

$\mathrm{Mercury} \  4498.7 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Venus \  X} \ 1939.8  \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Earth \  X} \ 10614.6 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Moon \ X} \ 7800.2 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Mars \  X} \ 445.2  \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Ceres \ X} \ 129.5  \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Pallas \ X} \ 432.4 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Juno \ X} \  151.4 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Vesta \ X} \  157.6 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Ida \ X} \ 73.6  \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Gaspra} \  455.3 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{9P/T1} \  241.5 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{19P/B} \ 402.7 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{67P/C-G} \  533.2 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{81P/W2} \  110.7  \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Jupiter} \ 172.3 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Saturn} \  261.2 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Uranus} \ 71.4  \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Neptune} \   31.3 \ \mathrm{km}$

$\mathrm{Pluto \  X \ } \ 45.7 \ \mathrm{km}$

As you see some planets have little desviations and some bigger, so my question is: Can Newton's be accurate? or Don Cross solar system calculator is not? Or there is black matter in that region? Or what else?

```
void CGravitator::CalcAceleration(double timeseconds){
unsigned int i,j,iend;
if (sunStatic)iend=m_np-1;
else iend=m_np;
for (i = 0; i < iend; i++) {
        m_planetas[i].aceleration.set(0,0,0);
        CVector3 totalGravitationalForce;                                       
        // Loop through all bodies in the universe to calculate their gravitational pull on the object (TODO: Ignore very far away objects for better performance)


     for (j = 0; j < m_np; j++) {
            if (i == j) continue; // No need to calculate the gravitational pull of a body on itself as it will always be 0.                                
            double distancia =CVector3::Distancia(m_planetas[i].pos,m_planetas[j].pos);
            double force = KGNEWTON * m_planetas[i].masa * m_planetas[j].masa / pow(distancia, 2);
            CVector3 forceDirection = CVector3::Normalize(m_planetas[j].pos - m_planetas[i].pos);
            
            totalGravitationalForce += forceDirection * force;
        }
            CVector3 incspeed = totalGravitationalForce / m_planetas[i].masa ;          
        m_planetas[i].aceleration += incspeed * timeseconds;
        
    
}
```

Comment: Are you calculating all the forces between the bodies, or just the force between each body and the Sun?

Comment: BTW, it's pretty easy to change your code from Euler integration to a symplectic integrator like Verlet or Leapfrog, and you'll be able to use a much larger time step.

Comment: "Can Newton's be accurate? or Don Cross solar system calculator is not?" When writing new simulation code it's always good to benchmark against something more well established. But when the results differ, the default assumption should be that the fault is with your code.

Comment: If you're porting code that uses the same method, it's a good idea to check that the same inputs (planet positions, time step, etc.) yields the same output, as jkej suggests. That's more of a coding exercise. Learning about the problems with certain numerical methods is more mathematical, and why certain methods are better for certain systems is more physics-y.

Comment: Hello, I sum all the forces between all bodies. The sun starts at (0,0,0) and can move or not(checkbox) but thes sun moving or not gave very similar results.My code from c++ traduction give the same results as Javascript source,  and Newton's code is very simple so there is no code error.

Comment: And after the acceleariotn code sum accel to speed and add speed *deltatime to position for each planet. I don't know is that if that is Eluler's method

Comment: @LuisALberto Yes. Calculating instantaneous velocity and acceleration, then using those together with $\Delta t$ to update position and velocity in a single step in the easiest way reasonable is the forward Euler method. Some more sophisticated general methods use the new positions and velocities to do corrections before moving on to the next timestep. That gets you into Runge-Kutta land.

Comment: This isn't [codereview.se] so I won't make this an answer, but a few tips for numerical stability and performance. #1 You're first multiplying and then dividing by `m_planetas[i].masa`. Cancel those out. (And change "force" in your variable names to "acceleration".) #2 You're first (presumably) taking a square root inside `CVector3::Distancia` and then squaring the distance. Cancel those out too. And #3 yes, avoid Euler integration. And #4 please include your actual velocity and position update code in your question — it might have bugs or numerical inaccuracies that affect your results.

Comment: @LuisALberto, are you using double precision (or higher precision) for your floating point calculations?

Comment: Numerical integration, especially of planetary motions, is hard, really hard. Some methods barely work, some are completely unstable and some need very good fine-tuning to get accurate results. The problem is not Newton: it is the difficulty of numerical integration.

Comment: One way that you can cross-check your program is to calculate the total momentum of all objects in your system.  This shouldn’t change, so any variation represents some kind of error.  You’ll always have some, but it should be very small.

Comment: Yes, Euler integration is the "obvious" algorithm: $\Delta v=a\Delta t$, $\Delta x=v\Delta t$. Rather than using mass, it's more accurate to use the [standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter); Horizons uses values that are *slightly* different from those on Wikipedia.

Comment: What are you using for your initial planet positions & velocities? Are you using the Don Cross program for that, or Horizons? BTW, the mean distance between the centre of the Sun and the Solar System barycentre is ~830,000 km, with a maximum around 1.5 million km. I have a graph (produced using Horizons) in [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/44903/16685).

Comment: There are many things that are wrong in the posted code. The biggest by far is that the technique does not use velocity. $a \Delta t$ (acceleration times time step) is change in velocity. It is not the planet's velocity. You need to integrate position and velocity, which means you need an initial position and an initial velocity.

Comment: @DavidHammen: That's a very good point. We don't know what OP's code does with `m_planetas[i].aceleration`, since they haven't posted the rest of it, but the value they store in that vector isn't an acceleration. (`incspeed` _is_ an acceleration, at least assuming that `totalGravitationalForce` is indeed a force, but then it gets multiplied by a time interval.)

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The code  I'm using now is from Wikipedia Verlet Newton(but results have tiny difference from above ). The velocities and positions are now are from Horizon files.I  also used preccision library GMP but is the  same. I also tried to search the sun mass (by code) but error only decreases to half. Maybe the speed of Horizon's files(deltatime 1 minute) is not perfect at moment.(Newton delta time is 0.1 seconds). Or maybe there is non uniform black matter?

Comment: I found that Horizon's speed for each time is not the exact speed at that time, is the average speed to the next time step, because adding position + speed  gives the next position (and not exact because x and y are perfect while z not¿¿¿¿WTF???? . So if using Horizon's file is needed to find the initial speed to set up Newton ok for calculating time step smaller than Horizon, becuase a tiny error at the start will grow and grow.

Answer (score 42):

You need to use a better numerical method. Euler’s method is notoriously bad for orbital mechanics because the numerical errors always accumulate. In particular, Euler’s method does not conserve energy, so you get orbits that just magically gain energy and spiral away out of control.

You need to use something like the Verlet method or some other symplectic integrator.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator

Comment: Thanks, but I used The Verlet code from wikipedia and got the same results

Comment: I would recommend using the JPL ephemerides for checking your computations: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/

Comment: Thanks, I tryed parsing Horizon files but got bigger errors!. Also its minimun time step is 0.5 seconds. Since some planets use the same code(in Don Cross source), and the ones with bigger errors  have smaller constats, I will try with a precission library like gmp, but it is tedious.

Comment: I doubt that gmp will help. You will just have the inaccurate positions to high precision.

Comment: You don't need to use a symplectic integrator. JPL does not use one, for example. They use a variable step size, variable order Adams family integrator.  Maybe Cowell or Gauss-Jackson? This are in the Adams family of numerical integrator, and both that position and velocity differently.

Comment: Dake, u are right the main error comes from walking in the wrong way. I'm again taking the data from Horizon files and error is related to distance from sun, (Mercury the biggest). So I think it's the mass, because it is not accurate. I will first simulate some mass suns, and take the best with min error to Horizon. Then go planet by planet doing the same.

Comment: @LuisALberto  But Mercury is not the biggest error, the Earth and Moon are, which is what really puzzles me about your question.  Normally Mercury *always* has the biggest error (for multiple reasons) so if something else is the biggest (Earth-Moon) that eliminates most of the normal single-cause culprits (non-symplectic integration, bad G, bad mass of the Sun, etc.)   What's distinct about the earth-moon system is the high angular tilt of the moon's orbit and the high mass of moon compared to it's primary (earth).  My gut is that there's something wrong with the source data or the z-calcs.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the deficiencies in the numerical method pointed out in the other answer, simulating Mercury's orbit must take into account Jupiter's gravitation, as well as relativistic effects. This only explains a tiny fraction of the deviation but should be considered when the numerical method gets better.

Apparently [the  perihelion precession of Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Perihelion_precession_of_Mercury) due to Jupiter's pull and relativistic effects is about 574 arcseconds in a century, or 1.57E-2 arcseconds/day. With an orbital circumference of about 3.6E8 km and an arcsecond being 1.296E-6 of a turn, that amounts to about 4.3km, or 43 km in 10 days.

While the difference in the position of the perihelion does not directly translate into a location difference it should give an idea of the effect.

Comment: thanks, this give me an idea of the error magnitude

Answer (score 2):

The error came from the data sources. Now I replaced to NAIF cspice.lib and download a general SPK file for only the planets, and the error is really small without other gravity bodies like asteorids and comets. Is really simple to use only 2 functions( furnsh_c and spkezr_c), an include and a lib.
 Coded with vc6++ pure win 32. I runned makeall.bat from spice unzipped.(couldn' make it work in MFC) 
Also time step can be any fraction of seconds so spice and newton are synchronized. So Newton tell's me that there is no black matter. 
Here are the results without asteroids and comets gravity for 10 days and no corrections in cpsice spkezr_c

distance error in KM newton(Verlet) from spice

 time = 864000.250

 MERCURY BARYCENTER =  5.511496277969209e+002 

SATURN BARYCENTER =  8.535731413118873e+001 

VENUS BARYCENTER =  2.701394194074592e+002 

URANUS BARYCENTER =  8.651056255887706e+001 

EARTH =  9.664941717935676e+001 

NEPTUNE BARYCENTER =  8.654038466254323e+001 

MOON =  1.208560265740111e+002 

MARS BARYCENTER =  5.954829440293592e+001 

PLUTO BARYCENTER =  8.661640570487361e+001 

JUPITER BARYCENTER =  8.256645190275238e+001 

TOTAL ERROR DISTANCE =  1.525933904320919e+003

 Time Ini GREGORIAN = 2000 JAN 01 12:00:00.000

 Time End  GREGORIAN = 2000 JAN 11 12:00:00.250